# Error when using tfexec golang package to fetch state: unsupported state format version: expected ["0.1" "0.2"], got "1.0"

Tags: go, terraform

For this code I'm getting the error unsupported state format version: expected ["0.1" "0.2"], got "1.0". Is this an issue with the terraform cli which I used to create the configurations?

Terraform cli version:

```
user@host dir % terraform --version
Terraform v1.5.2
on darwin_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v5.7.0

Your version of Terraform is out of date! The latest version
is 1.5.4. You can update by downloading from https://www.terraform.io/downloads.html
```

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/hashicorp/terraform-exec/tfexec"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() ([]string, error) {
    tfPath, lookpath_err := exec.LookPath("terraform")
    if lookpath_err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to find `terraform` in your $PATH (need to install Terraform first): %s", lookpath_err)
    }
    tfpath := "/path/to/dir"
    tf, newtf_err := tfexec.NewTerraform(tfpath, tfPath)
    if newtf_err != nil {
        error_msg := fmt.Sprintf("Error running NewTerraform: %s", newtf_err)
        return []string{""}, errors.New(error_msg)
    }

    _, tfshow_err := tf.ShowStateFile(context.Background(), tfpath+"/.terraform/terraform.tfstate")
    if tfshow_err != nil {
        error_msg := fmt.Sprintf("Error running terraform show: %s", tfshow_err)
        return []string{""}, errors.New(error_msg)
    }

    return []string{"SUCCESS"}, nil
}
```

Running this code gave an error output expected a tfjson object